# Transform Single<List<Maybe<Book>>> to Single<List<Book>>

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

could someone help, please?

I have these functions

```
fun getBooks(): Single<List<Book>> {
    return getCollections()
        .map {
            it.map(::collectonToBook)
        }
}

fun getCollections(): Single<List<Collection>> {
   return db.fetchCollections()
       .filter(::isBook)
}

fun collectonToBook(collection: Collection): Maybe<Book> {
    return collection.toBook()
}
```

The problem is getBooks returns `Single<List<Maybe<Book>>>` when I need `Single<List<Book>>`. Can I do that inside the stream without calling blockingGet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```kotlin
getCollections()                        // Single<List<Collection>>
.flattenAsFlowable { it }               // Flowable<Collection>
.concatMapMaybe { collectonToBook(it) } // Flowable<Book>
.toList()                               // Single<List<Book>>
```

In words, unwrap the inner `List` into its elements, transform the `Collection` into a `Book`, concatenate their respective `Maybe` sources, then finally collect the `Book`s into a `List` again.

Comment: Wow! It works like a miracle, Thank you so much. And for quick response as well! Cheers!